# Any ideas how to slove problem with activation function?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a problem with loading self pretrained keras model.
When i make predictions directly after training model everything works fine.

My code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import load_model
"""
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
"""
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()


# Reshaping the array to 4-dims so that it can work with the Keras API
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
# Making sure that the values are float so that we can get decimal points after division
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
# Normalizing the RGB codes by dividing it to the max RGB value.
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('Number of images in x_train', x_train.shape[0])
print('Number of images in x_test', x_test.shape[0])
# Importing the required Keras modules containing model and layers


def train():
    # Creating a Sequential Model and adding the layers
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(28, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten()) # Flattening the 2D arrays for fully connected layers
    model.add(Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train, epochs=10)
    print(model.summary())
    model.save('x.h5')


def eval():
    model = load_model('x.h5')
    scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))


train()
eval()
```

And i got an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown activation function:softmax_v2
```

I've tried to use different tensorflow versions (1.15, 2.0, 1.5) but this changes nothing.
Any ideas what is wrong with it?
Edit:
This problem occurs only when i try to load model.

Comment: `model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))` and `model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))`

Comment: which tf version are you using?